# How to slide from left to call Appbar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a project that require you call Appbar if slide left, so in my phone if i slide from left it should call the appbar.

my idea is to wrap the scalfolding with a container, but i dont a way which if i can detect a swipe `without moving` to call the app bar

Comment: So you want to show the appbar after sliding left and have disabled it until then?

Comment: Hi, Gbenga. What do you mean by "call the AppBar", as the app bar is a bar on the top usually with a screen title or icons. Maybe you mean to open a drawer (menu list usually on the left) when sliding from the left?

Comment: @George yes open the drawer when you slide from left... just like twitter app on Android

Comment: @JustLearnedIt just show the drawer after sliding from left...

Comment: thats what a drawer will autmatically do. just use `Scaffold(drawer: ...)`

Comment: call the app bar or show the drawer? as for example android's native drawer works?

Comment: @OMiShah let use twitter Andriod as example if you slide from the left it will open the drawer... that is what i want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

To open the drawer do this

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
       automaticallyImplyLeading: false
    ), 
    drawer: Drawer(), 
    body: ...
);
```

But if you want to change the drawer button icon do this instead

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
       leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => IconButton(
             padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
             icon: //your icon,
             onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()
          ), 
       ), 
    ), 
    drawer: Drawer(), 
    body: ...
);
```

Comment: i undestand this code very well... All i wan to if you slide from left, it shd call the openDrawer

Comment: let use twitter Andriod as example if you slide from the left it will open the drawer... that is what i want to achieve

Comment: The flutter Drawer do what you want by default no need to add anything else.

Comment: yes, i understand, the project i am working on require this features

Comment: Okay. Maybe I'm not getting what you really want but someone will do.